# Manual iPhone rotation incorrectly positioned

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation

I've managed to manually detect rotation and set my own rotation effects between two UIViewControllers. When in the first, rotating to landscape prompts the second to be pushed on with a manual animation. The status bar moves to the correct orientation. However, the view loaded by the second UIViewController is not in the position I expected it. Instead there is margin on the left where the status bar previously was and margin/space at the bottom that I was expecting to be filled by the view.

[image: How the rotation appears]

(Click to enlarge. The orange box is simply to reference where 0,0 is in the rotated UIView, CustomView)

The code I'm using in my view controller to do the rotation is:

```
-(void)loadView {
    CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 480, 300)];
    self.view = customView;

    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
    [self.view setTransform:rotate];

    [customView release];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT** Managed to solve after a variety of trial and error approaches - answer provided below. Perhaps there's a more elegant/obvious solution though - if so feel free to provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by setting the View's bounds after the transformation:

```
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(20, -20, 480, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

try these on the viewcontrollers. Solved the 20 pixel(status bar height) clip issue when I was getting fullscreen subviews to show up.

[viewcontroller1.view setCenter:CGPointMake(viewcontroller1.view.center.x, viewcontroller1.view.center.y-20)];

and/or

[viewcontroller2.view setCenter:CGPointMake(viewcontroller2.view.center.x-20, viewcontroller2.view.center.y)];